# Why does do_execve() perform executable verification check in two steps instead of one?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, executable, file-permissions, execve

Understanding the Linux Kernel says about the implementation of `execve()`:

> `do_execve( )` performs the following operations:
>
> 1. Dynamically allocates a `linux_binprm` data structure, which will be filled with data concerning the new executable file.
> 2. Invokes `path_lookup(), dentry_open()`, and `path_release()` to get the dentry object, the file object, and the inode object associated
>      with the executable file. On failure, it returns the proper error
>      code.
> 3. **Verifies that the file is executable by the current process**; also, checks that the file is not being written by looking at the
>      `i_writecount` field of the `inode`; stores –1 in that field to forbid
>      further write accesses.
> 4. In multiprocessor systems, it invokes the `sched_exec()` function to determine the least loaded CPU that can execute the new program and
>      to migrate the current process to it (see Chapter 7).
> 5. Invokes `init_new_context()` to check whether the current process was using a custom Local Descriptor Table (see the section “The Linux
>      LDTs” in Chapter 2); in this case, the function allocates and fills a
>      new LDT to be used by the new program.
> 6. Invokes the `prepare_binprm( )` function to fill the `linux_binprm` data structure. This function, in turn, performs the following
>      operations:
>
>    a. **Checks again whether the file is executable (at least one execute
>      access right is set)**; if not, returns an error code. (**The previous
>      check in step 3 is not sufficient** because a process with the
>      `CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE` capability set always satisfies the check; see the
>      section “Process Credentials and Capabilities” earlier in this
>      chapter).
>
> ...

Do step 3 and step 6a both perform verification check that the execution permission bit of the executable file is set for the process?

What are their differences and relations?

Does step 3 not take into account the `CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE` capacity of the process, while step 6a does? Is this the only difference between the two steps?

Why do we need the two-step check, instead of one-step check by lumping all the check into step 3 or step 6a?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can **and should** read the kernel source itself (this is in fs/exec.c). Steps 2 and 3 are basically invoking the common *open* function with special *EXEC* flags "open file with intent to execute", whereas the second check is part of a series of checks "what rights should the new process have".

so to the more specific bits:

- what is this supposed to prevent? => probably root executing non-executable binaries by mistake
- why not do the check in 3? => this is reusing a more general operation -open with flags-, that operation should succeed if you have the capability for it
- why not do all the checking in 6? => 3 does many additional checks that would be impractical here, like "are we on a noexec mounted fs?"

Anyway, your question is a bit too open, not sure my answer will satisfy you. Do go and read the kernel source instead. :-)